# If I polymorph myself using a wand, does my inventory change too?

Tags: nethack

I'm about to try eating some rings by polymorphing myself with a wand of polymorph and ring of poly control, and there have been a lot of monster generations while I've tried other risky things (armor testing in Ft Ludios). I don't want to take off my amulet of Reflection, rings (polycontrol and =4 Protection), nor do I want to drop my wands (MM, lightning, teleport). Will they change , too?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Your inventory is not affected during self-polymorph, with the sole exception of *worn* armor potentially breaking. If you zap yourself with a wand of polymorph, the only thing that will change is You.

Similarly, zapping a monster with the wand or spell will not affect that monster's carried items. The ray may hit items on the ground before or after the monster, but items will only be affected by the wand/spell of polymorph if they are on the floor.